# How to use RaycastHit.Point in Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am Ray-casting from camera to center of screen like below :

```
 Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
```

i can access the hitPoint using

```
RaycastHit hit;
  hit.point;
```

and i am placing the Crosshair at the hit position but i want to position the cross hair in the direction of raycast just few units away from camera How do i do that? Because someTimes the hit position can be really far i want a fix distance to place crosshair in the direction raycast.

Comment: Can you just use x and y from the hitpoint and use a constant for z, such as 1.0f, or however far you want the fix distance to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
Vector3 position = (hit.point - Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f))).normalize * length;
```

Comment: Thanks ! but i used Ray.GetPoint() method for that.